# Insert a string on a new line after a pattern

Tags: sed

I want to replace

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

by

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
```

so far, I came to:

```bash
 #!/bin/bash                                                                                                              
 newString='\\addto\\captionsfrench{\\def\\tablename{Tableau}}'                                                                                                                                              
 sed -i "/babel.*/a $newString"  $1
```

which almost does the job
The problem I encounter is that if I write newString='\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}'  the backslash before \addto is absent, and if I escape the backslash \addto I obtain ^Gaddto
~

Comment: Wrong dupe, as OP is already using an escaped string in `newString='\\addto\\captionsfrench{\\def\\tablename{Tableau}}'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `sed` should work for you with `a` (append) command:

```bash
cat file

\usepackage[french]{babel}

newString='\\addto\\captionsfrench{\\def\\tablename{Tableau}}'
sed -i.bak "/{babel}/a\\
$newString
" file

cat file

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
```

PS: Note that we are using double `\\` after `a` since main sed script is inside the double quotes.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that I needed the double backslash before $newString.

Answer (score 2):

sed is fine for the shown example but FWIW I'd use awk for literal string replacements in general since [sed doesn't understand literal strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed), e.g. using any POSIX awk:

```
new='\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}' \
awk '1; /babel/{print ENVIRON["new"]}' file
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
```

If the target string you wanted to match on could contain backslashes and/or regexp metachars then you'd use either of these depending on whether you wanted to do a full-line match:

```
tgt='\usepackage[french]{babel}' \
new='\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}' \
awk '1; $0==ENVIRON["tgt"]{print ENVIRON["new"]}' file
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
```

or a partial-line match:

```
tgt='\usepackage[french]{babel}' \
new='\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}' \
awk '1; index($0,ENVIRON["tgt"]){print ENVIRON["new"]}' file
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
```

Note that you don't need to escape the backslashes, they're just one more literal character to awk when used this way, see [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script).

Comment: Indeed awk is better tool for literal string search and replacement.

Comment: I have just seen your answer (didn't checked after the first answer because I had a working solution). Thanks for your detailed explanations.